# Django filter by week

Tags: python, django, date, python-datetime

Is there a way to easily filter Date objects by week? Basically I want to do something like

`items= RelevantObject.objects.filter(date__week=32)`

I've found that it's possible to do this for year and month, but it doesn't seem like the capability for week is built in. Is there a "right" way to do this? It seems like it shouldn't be too difficult.

Thanks

Comment: In your example, do you mean to say get records for 32nd week of the year ?

Comment: @karthikr Yes, that's exactly what I meant by that.

Comment: and for the current year only right? 32nd week of 2012 for example ?

Comment: Either that, or have another attribute (`date__year=2013`, for example). In fact, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no predefined query field lookup that can do this for weeks.  I'd either reuse code from the WeekArchiveView date-based generic view, or ideally directly subclass it - it already handles the filtering.